# Libvirt Domain.InterfaceStats network io i/o always zero

Tags: xen, libvirt

Hello,I use function "Domain.InterfaceStats" to get network i/o  statistics,but always get things like these:vif1.0 rx_bytes 0 vif1.0 rx_packets 0 vif1.0 rx_errs 0 vif1.0 rx_drop 0
 vif1.0 tx_bytes 0 vif1.0 tx_packets 0 vif1.0 tx_errs 0 vif1.0 tx_drop 0. and it seems  statistics is always zero. How can I fix it?

In addition,I use HVM.and xen version is 4.2, libvirt version is 1.1.2.and network is set as default just bridge.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the vm system is window, maybe install gplpv driver can be helpful.